Customize bashrc for new user on Yocto (petalinux)
I have created a recipe for adding a new user.
inherit extra users

SRC_URI = "file://.bashrc"
FILES_${PN} = "/home/user/.bashrc"

EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "useradd -u 1200 -d /home/user/ -p '' -s /bin/rbash user"

ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "modify_default_bashrc;"

modify_default_bashrc () {
     mkdir -p {D}/home/user
     install ${WORKINGDIR}/.bashrc ${D}/home/user
}

The goal is to create a non root user, who can run a restricted set of commands. To do this I set rbash as default, also I created /home/user/bin and put links to the set of commands that this user can run. The final step was to set the PATH variable to /home/user/bin in the /home/user/.bashrc
Unfortunately after I run my recipe the .bashrc file is set to a default one and I don't know how to modify it.
How can I add a custom .bashrc for a custom user?
or
Is there a better way to restrict a user?

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Perhaps adding -M to the useradd will stop it creating the home directory and copying the overriding skeleton files there.

@Barmar I know what I need to do, the question is what is the code that generates the desired outcome

Do you think the code for doing this in a shell script is different from doing it by hand? If not, then it's a Unix question, not a programming question.

This is not a shell script.

you can use the usermod command inside the creation script to alter your new user default shell to custom-shell.
first you need to add the custom shell to /etc/shells (this file contains valid pathnames to login shells).
after you can alter the default user shell to the new one
sudo usermod --shell /bin/bash ${username}

for more information you can read this article from GeeksForGeeks

I successfully set the user's shell to rbash with the -s option when I create the user. The problem is how do I restrict the set of commands that the user can execute?

all commands are a single file in unix, you can see what file is related to a command with wich ${command} this will be the entry-point for a command, one approach is to list all commands that the user can execute, create a GROUP with permissions to the files, and deny all other files, than add the new user to this GROUP
